# Print the first three characters of each item in the list which has more than 5 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, slice

```
items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Eggfruit", "Fig"]
for word in items:
   print(word[:3])
#prints the first three characters of each item

def string_k(k, str):
  string = []
  text = str.split(" ")
  for x in text:
    if len(x) > k:
      string.append(x)
  return string
k = 6
str = "Apple, Banana, Cherry, Date, Eggfruit, Fig"
print(string_k(k, str))
#This prints out every item in the list that has more than five characters
```

This is similar to my first question - i have the two separate codes but i don't understand how to get them together to get the output that i need

Comment: `print('\n'.join(s[:3] for s in items if len(s)>5))`

Comment: ok, i will try that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Eggfruit", "Fig"]
for item in items:
  if len(item) >= 5:
    print(item[:3])
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `enumerate` here. You can just use `for item in items` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` here.

```
items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Eggfruit", "Fig"]

for _str in filter(lambda x:len(x)>=5,items):
    print(_str[:3])
```

---

Output:

```
App
Ban
Che
Egg
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work better than your code.

```
items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Eggfruit", "Fig"]
for i in range(0, len(items)):
    if len(i) >= 5:
        print(i[:3])
```